# Select only drop-down menu that has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that includes a column for the user to select from a drop-down menu to populate the next column.  Problem is the table contains the same drop-down menu for each row and on change when I select using the following syntax JQuery selects all drop-downs instead of just the one in that has actually changed.  Below solution uses event.stopImmediatePropagation() to act similar to a break point and is the only solution I can think of that will work.  Please let me know if there is a more elegant solution out there...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="selected_client[id]" id="selected_client_id" class="selected_client">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="240">CLIENT ONE</option>
        <option value="195">CLIENT TWO</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="selected_client[id]" id="selected_client_id" class="selected_client">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="240">CLIENT ONE</option>
        <option value="195">CLIENT TWO</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

$j('.selected_client').change(function(event) {
        var client_id = $j(this).val(); // <-- value of the drop down that was currently changed
        var tmp_row = $j(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
        // perform action

        event.stopImmediatePropagation();  // prevents calling other matched rows
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Starting to think that on focus of the drop-down to add a class that could be identify a particular row and on unfocus remove class could solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using event.stopImmediatePropagation(); proved successfully and simply acts as a break which is useful for the scenario when you are dealing with dynamic entities where selecting by id does not quite solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

First off, id's need to be unique. A class would be better suited for this purpose.

```
$('.selected_client').change(function(){
   $(this).val(); // <-- value of the drop down that was currently changed
});
```

Comment: Getting close in the fact it returns the correct value each time, however my solution basically does the same, problem is this code is of course executed for all rows and not just for the one row that has changed.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could differentiate the element IDs for each row, example: the first select element would have an id of "selected_client_id01", the second one "selected_client_id02" and so forth. And then only assign functions to all elements with that one class "selected_client".